# How to create a Program/Command that will search files for every instance of "Real" and then replace them with "double."

Tags: c

I just started coding in C. I need to create a program/command that will search through the various program files and directories, locate any instances of the word "Real" and then replace them with the word "double". This program/command will need to be able to search though .c and .h files (and possibly more).

Basically, I would like to avoid having to search through thousands of lines of code, and dozens of files, just to retype the word "Real" as "double". As you are aware, these are variable types, and I need to change one to the other. Any ideas? Thoughts?

Comment: you can just use grep and sed

Comment: So, 'Real a;' needs to become 'double a;'.

Comment: Can you use `#define Real double`?

Comment: What is `Real` ? What's wrong with a `typedef` or a `#define`?

Comment: You could just do something along the line of `find . -type f -iname "*.c" | xargs -i perl -p -i -e "s/Real/double/g" {}`

Comment: Thank you @ssube ! How do I use grep and sed to accomplish this? Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @L.Jarboe Look at the answers you've been given; there is a `sed` example.

Answer (score 5):

`sed -e 's/Real/double/g'`

On your input files...

> I realize that this may require multiple programs (one for each file type).

Nope, that's completely false.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I use your command above "sed -e 's/Real/double/g'" it will search through and change Real to double in every file type? Also, I am guessing I should enter your command while in the top directory of athena, or will I have to go into every directory and type that in the command line? @djechlin

Comment: @L.Jarboe I'm going to leave it up to you to learn the very basics of how sed works. Start by writing a very simple file "This is Real, Reality is Real" and replace Real with double. You'll have to get better at unix/bash to figure out how to input a huge number of files into it at once (see your Q's comment using `find`). You probably want `sed -i` to modify "in place."

Comment: Note this has its limits...  it will turn the word "Really" to "doublely".

Answer (score 1):

Create a `typedef` instead:

```
typedef double Real;
```

Now any instance of `Real` is an alias to `double`.

You **don't** want to use a simple text find/replace tool like `sed` since that could potentially change the string "Real" which appears in comments, string constants, or as part of another identifier such as `getRealUser`.

Comment: Should I type 'typedef double Real;' at the top of each file before the global variables are listed? Or will I need to insert it in/before every function, etc.

Comment: @L.Jarboe Only at the top of each source file.  Actually, if you have a single .h file that all your source files use, you only need to do it once in that .h file.

Comment: @L.Jarboe Also, `Real` isn't a predefined type in C.  Where is that definition coming from?

Comment: Fantastic. Also, I just changed my user name from L.Jarboe to ekuljarb. I believe 'Real' is a type created/defined in the program I'm using. It is an old (10+ years) program.

Comment: @ekuljarb If that's the case, then you need to find that definition and change it.

Answer (score 1):

What about looking in to some intelligent text editors, like Notepad++ (https://notepad-plus-plus.org)? It has the capability to search across multiple files, multiple folders and multiple extensions, also using Regular Expressions.

In general, anyway, editing code with find-and-replace utilities would be not my first choice. When writing C code, it's better to use some `typedef` keywords, or some preprocessor related stuff, to write a code which is more editable and scalable in the future.

Comment: Why introduce some heavy IDE for a simple text replace?

Comment: I don't even know if we are talking about Windows, as a development environment. You're right, sed and grep are quite powerful and fast tools, but could be not the easiest solution. But... I'm mainly a Windows programmer, so I'm quite used to heavy IDEs. Anyway, I don't think that Notepad++ is heavy, it's quite fast and straightforward, in my opinion.

Comment: How on earth could sed possibly not be the easiest solution? And I'm sure Windows has some equivalent?